# c++ scrabble score searching for a word

Tags: c++, search

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int score(string s);
char scrabbleLetters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
int scrabblePoints[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int main()
{
    string sWord;
    cout << "Enter the scrabble word you'd like to score.";
    cin >> sWord;
    cout << "You scored " << score(sWord)<< " points for that word!";

}

int score(string s)
{   int points = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < scrabbleLetters.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
                points += scrabblePoints[j];
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

the code is suppose to ask the user for a input word and provide the scrabble score but it doesnt seem to compile it gives me an error error: request for member 'length' in 'scrabbleLetters', which is of non-class type 'char [26]'|"

Comment: C++ raw arrays don't have a `.length()` method. You can do `sizeof(scrabbleLetters)/sizeof(char)` to calculate the length of the array, or you can use a standard library container like `std::vector` or `std::array` which will have a `length` method. (For a larger redesign, I'd consider using an `std::unordered_map<char, int>` instead of maintaining two parallel data structures, but the functionality should be fine either way.)

Answer (score 1):

`scrabbleLetters` is an array. Arrays don't have a `length` function to call. You'll need to determine the length of the array another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because `scrabbleLetters` is an array and it does not have `length` method to call, so you need to calculate it.

you take the size of the entire array and divide it by the size of the type.

```
int score(string s)
{   int points = 0;
    int length = sizeof(scrabbleLetters)/sizeof(char);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
                points += scrabblePoints[j];
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```